# Тестовые данные из src не сохраняются в build

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть проект на nestjs, где мне нужно обращаться ко внутренней файловой системе для хранения некоторых директорий и файлов. Изначально проект пустой и я хочу заполнить  его тестовыми файлами(фото, txt), поэтому создал скрипт, который рандомно берет эти тестовые файлы и вставляет в директории. Но проблема заключается в том, что nest игнорирует директорию "assets", которая находится в src во время разработки, соответственно в build'е этой директории не появляется и выходит ошибка

Функция createPath создает готовый path для root-директории

```js
import { resolve } from "path"


export const createPath = (path1: string, path2?: string) => {
    if (!path2) return resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', path1)
    else return resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', path1, path2)
}
```

```js
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { createPath } from './createPath';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export const insertTestData = () => {
  const paths = [
    'c/documents/testFolder1',
    'c/documents/testFolder2',
    'c/documents/testFolder3',
    'c/documents/testFolder4',
    'c/documents/testFolder5',
    'c/games/testFolder1',
    'c/games/testFolder2',
    'c/games/testFolder3',
    'c/games/testFolder4',
    'c/admin/testFolder1',
    'c/admin/testFolder2',
    'c/admin/testFolder3',
    'd/other/testFolder1',
    'd/other/testFolder2',
    'd/other/testFolder3',
    'd/other/testFolder4',
    'd/other/testFolder5',
    'd/photo/testFolder1',
    'd/photo/testFolder2',
    'd/photo/testFolder3',
    'e/video/testFolder1',
    'e/video/testFolder2',
    'e/video/testFolder3',
    'e/video/testFolder4',
    'e/video/testFolder5',
  ];
  // в этом месте появляется ошибка, т.к. assets не появляется в dist

  const assetsPath = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'assets');
  const testFiles = fs.readdirSync(assetsPath);
  
  for (let path of paths) {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    for (let fileNum = 0; fileNum < randomNum; fileNum++) {
      const file = fs.readFileSync(
        resolve(__dirname, assetsPath, testFiles[fileNum]),
      );
      if (!fs.existsSync(createPath(path))) fs.mkdirSync(createPath(path));

      fs.writeFileSync(createPath(path, testFiles[fileNum]), file);
    }
  }
};
```